# Cannot import TensorFlow in pycharm

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

Cannot import tensorFlow in pycharm using Anaconda environments. I created a virtual python environment (python 3.6) which I called tensor, installed tensorFlow using pip, set the PATH environment variable (system and user). In pycharm I set the interpreter to tensor (C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\pythonw.exe).

When I run import tensorFlow I get this:

(tensor) C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\tensorEnv>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\tensorEnv\test.py", line 1, in 
    import tensorFlow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorFlow'

(tensor) C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\tensorEnv>